# Optimizing LINQ routines

Tags: c#, performance, multithreading, sql-server, entity-framework

I run a build system. Datawise the simplified description would be that I have Configurations and each config has 0..n Builds. 
Now builds produce artifacts and some of these are stored on server. What I am doing is writing kind of a rule, that sums all the bytes produced per configuration builds and checks if these are too much.

The code for the routine at the moment is following:

```
private void CalculateExtendedDiskUsage(IEnumerable<Configuration> allConfigurations)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    // Lets take only confs that have been updated within last 7 days
    var items = allConfigurations.AsParallel().Where(x =>
        x.artifact_cleanup_type != null && x.build_cleanup_type != null &&
        x.updated_date > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7)
        ).ToList();

    using (var ctx = new LocalEntities())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Context: " + sw.Elapsed);
        var allBuilds = ctx.Builds;
        var ruleResult = new List<Notification>();
        foreach (var configuration in items)
        {
            // all builds for current configuration
            var configurationBuilds = allBuilds.Where(x => x.configuration_id == configuration.configuration_id)
                .OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
            Debug.WriteLine("Filter conf builds: " + sw.Elapsed);

            // Since I don't know which builds/artifacts have been cleaned up, calculate it manually
            if (configuration.build_cleanup_count != null)
            {
                var buildCleanupCount = "30"; // default
                if (configuration.build_cleanup_type.Equals("ReserveBuildsByDays"))
                {
                    var buildLastCleanupDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-int.Parse(buildCleanupCount));
                    configurationBuilds = configurationBuilds.Where(x => x.build_date > buildLastCleanupDate)
                            .OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
                }
                if (configuration.build_cleanup_type.Equals("ReserveBuildsByCount"))
                {
                    var buildLastCleanupCount = int.Parse(buildCleanupCount);
                    configurationBuilds =
                        configurationBuilds.Take(buildLastCleanupCount).OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
                }
            }

            if (configuration.artifact_cleanup_count != null)
            {
                // skipped, similar to previous block
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Done cleanup: " + sw.Elapsed);
            const int maxDiscAllocationPerConfiguration = 1000000000; // 1GB
            // Sum all disc usage per configuration
            var confDiscSizePerConfiguration = configurationBuilds
                .GroupBy(c => new {c.configuration_id})
                .Where(c => (c.Sum(z => z.artifact_dir_size) > maxDiscAllocationPerConfiguration))
                .Select(groupedBuilds =>
                    new
                    {
                        configurationId = groupedBuilds.FirstOrDefault().configuration_id,
                        configurationPath = groupedBuilds.FirstOrDefault().configuration_path,
                        Total = groupedBuilds.Sum(c => c.artifact_dir_size),
                        Average = groupedBuilds.Average(c => c.artifact_dir_size)
                    }).ToList();
            Debug.WriteLine("Done db query: " + sw.Elapsed);

            ruleResult.AddRange(confDiscSizePerConfiguration.Select(iter => new Notification
            {
                ConfigurationId = iter.configurationId,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                RuleType = (int) RulesEnum.TooMuchDisc,
                ConfigrationPath = iter.configurationPath
            }));
            Debug.WriteLine("Finished loop: " + sw.Elapsed);
        }
        // find owners and insert...
    }
}
```

This does exactly what I want, but I am thinking if I could make it any faster. Currenly I see:

```
Context: 00:00:00.0609067
// first round
Filter conf builds: 00:00:00.0636291
Done cleanup: 00:00:00.0644505
Done db query: 00:00:00.3050122
Finished loop: 00:00:00.3062711
// avg round
Filter conf builds: 00:00:00.0001707
Done cleanup: 00:00:00.0006343
Done db query: 00:00:00.0760567
Finished loop: 00:00:00.0773370
```

The `SQL` generated by `.ToList()` [looks very messy.](http://pastebin.com/RHFDYKtk) (Everything that is used in `WHERE` is covered with an index in DB)

I am testing with 200 configurations, so this adds up to 00:00:18.6326722. I have a total of ~8k items that need to get processed daily (so the whole routine takes more than 10 minutes to complete).

I have been randomly googling around this internet and it seems to me that `Entitiy Framework` is not very good with parallel processing. Knowing that I still decided to give this `async/await` approch a try (First time a tried it, so sorry for any nonsense).

Basically if I move all the processing out of scope like:

```
        foreach (var configuration in items)
        {

            var confDiscSizePerConfiguration = await GetData(configuration, allBuilds);

            ruleResult.AddRange(confDiscSizePerConfiguration.Select(iter => new Notification
            {
               ... skiped
        }
```

And:

```
private async Task<List<Blabla>> GetData(Configuration configuration, IQueryable<Build> allBuilds)
        {
                var configurationBuilds = allBuilds.Where(x => x.configuration_id == configuration.configuration_id)
                    .OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
                //..skipped
                var confDiscSizePerConfiguration = configurationBuilds
                    .GroupBy(c => new {c.configuration_id})
                    .Where(c => (c.Sum(z => z.artifact_dir_size) > maxDiscAllocationPerConfiguration))
                    .Select(groupedBuilds =>
                        new Tmp
                        {
                            ConfigurationId = groupedBuilds.FirstOrDefault().configuration_id,
                            ConfigurationPath = groupedBuilds.FirstOrDefault().configuration_path,
                            Total = groupedBuilds.Sum(c => c.artifact_dir_size),
                            Average = groupedBuilds.Average(c => c.artifact_dir_size)
                        }).ToListAsync();
            return await confDiscSizePerConfiguration;
    }
```

This, for some reason, drops the execution time for 200 items from 18 -> 13 sec. Anyway, from what I understand, since I am `await`ing each `.ToListAsync()`, it is still processed in sequence, is that correct?

So the "can't process in parallel" claim starts coming out when I replace the `foreach (var configuration in items)` with `Parallel.ForEach(items, async configuration =>`. Doing this change results in:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any
>   asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
>   on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

It was a bit confusing to me at first as I `await` practically in every place where the compiler allows it, but possibly the data gets seeded to fast.

I tried to overcome this by being less greedy and added the `new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4}` to that parallel loop, peasant assumption was that default connection pool size is 100, all I want to use is 4, should be plenty. But it still fails.

I have also tried to create new DbContexts inside the `GetData` method, but it still fails. If I remember correctly (can't test now), I got

> Underlying connection failed to open

What possibilities there are to make this routine go faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> var items = allConfigurations.AsParallel().Where(x =>
>     x.artifact_cleanup_type != null && x.build_cleanup_type != null &&
>     x.updated_date > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7)
>     ).ToList();
> ```

For each `Configuration` the `DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays()` method will be called. By precalculating this value and storing in a variable it will perform better.

```
var updated = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7);
var items = allConfigurations.AsParallel().Where(x =>
    x.artifact_cleanup_type != null && x.build_cleanup_type != null &&
    x.updated_date > updated
    ).ToList();
```

> ```
>         if (configuration.build_cleanup_count != null)
>         {
>             var buildCleanupCount = "30"; // default
>             if (configuration.build_cleanup_type.Equals("ReserveBuildsByDays"))
>             {
>                 var buildLastCleanupDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-int.Parse(buildCleanupCount));
>                 configurationBuilds = configurationBuilds.Where(x => x.build_date > buildLastCleanupDate)
>                         .OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
>             }
>             if (configuration.build_cleanup_type.Equals("ReserveBuildsByCount"))
>             {
>                 var buildLastCleanupCount = int.Parse(buildCleanupCount);
>                 configurationBuilds =
>                     configurationBuilds.Take(buildLastCleanupCount).OrderByDescending(z =>  z.build_date);
>             }
>         }
> ```

Having `var buildCleanupCount = "30";` and later use `int.Parse()` doesn't buy you anything but worse performance. If you name that variable `buildCleanupDefaultCount` you can remove the comment.

```
        if (configuration.build_cleanup_count != null)
        {
            var buildCleanupDefaultCount = 30; 
            if (configuration.build_cleanup_type.Equals("ReserveBuildsByDays"))
            {
                var buildLastCleanupDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-buildCleanupDefaultCount);
                configurationBuilds = 
                    configurationBuilds.Where(x => x.build_date > buildLastCleanupDate)
                                       .OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
            }
            if (configuration.build_cleanup_type.Equals("ReserveBuildsByCount"))
            {
                configurationBuilds =
                    configurationBuilds.Take(buildCleanupDefaultCount)
                                       .OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thing I'd try hard to get rid of is the loop. Calling a DB in a loop is rarely a good idea.

First option might be to try to do an equivalent of `IN` query:

```
var ids = items.Select(x => x.configuration_id)
var configurationBuilds = allBuilds.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.configuration_id)).OrderByDescending(z => z.build_date);
```

and then do the rest of your processing.

`IN` has a limit, but it lies 'in thousands of elements', so 200 configurations should be OK. As always - you have to profile to see which option is truly faster.

Otherwise, you can do basic batching and do e.g. 10 database calls with 20 clauses in `IN` query, possibly in parallel.

Also, `AsParallel` here:

```
var allConfigurations.AsParallel().Where(x =>
        x.artifact_cleanup_type != null && x.build_cleanup_type != null &&
        x.updated_date > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7)
        ).ToList();
```

will probably do you more harm than good. Parallel processing of a collection so small with an operation that's not CPU-intensive will probably be even slower than regular, sequential processing.